# Compiling typescript with Webpack for other projects

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, typescript-typings

How can I compile my Typescript project into a TS compilation so I can then import it into other TS projects and use the type definitions? For backward compatibility, I also want to export them as pure JS too so others who don't use TS, can still use the project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish your project as an npm package. You can create a private package on npm if you want (but you need a paid account for that), or you can publish it publicly, or you can use [sinopia](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sinopia), which is basically a local instance of npm.

Any one of these options requires you to have an up to date package.json file that specifies your project's dependencies.

You will be publishing your package in compiled form. So, if you specify your tsconfig and package.json properly, you will be exporting js files along with d.ts. files and the package will be usable either by typescript or vanilla javascript.

Comment: I understand how a project is published. I do not know (or could not find any documentation), on the configuration requires to compile and export the JS and the d.ts files

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've done it:

```
// package.json
// The property name: @my-org/... means that the package is scoped - 
// you can point a @scope at a specific NPM registry.
// See https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope
// We use myget.org to host our private packages.
{
  "name": "@my-org/ng-lib",
  "version": "1.0.8",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "transpile": "tsc --outDir ./",
    "clean": "rimraf ./services && rimraf ./*.js && rimraf ./*.d.ts"
  },
  "author": "*** <me@my-org.com>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "files": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ],
  "typings": "index.d.ts",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.20",
    "angular": "^1.5.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4"
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Notice the **"typings": "index.d.ts"** line? That describes the main "types" file for the package. So when you do an **import * as ngLib from '@my-org/ng-lib'** it will use the typings from node_modules/@my-org/ng-lib/index.d.ts for intellisense, and upon transpile webpack will find the main js file at **node_modules/@my-org/ng-lib/dist/index.js**

So if you've created an index.d.ts by hand and all you've got to export are interfaces you can point the typings field at that index.d.ts as interfaces have no implementation, and just describe the shape of an object.

However, if you've got objects with logic (methods, getters/setters, etc) they will more than likely be classes, which you'll need to transpile down to .js AND .d.ts files.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
./index.ts # Re-exports both my-class and my-interface
./my-class.ts # Implements my-interface.d.ts
./my-interface.d.ts
```

This output of this after transpile should be as follows in a "typed" NPM package:

```
./index.d.ts
./index.js
./my-class.js
./my-class.d.ts
./my-interface.d.ts
```

And package.json will include the following lines:

```
"main": "./index.js",
"typings": "./index.d.ts",
"files": [
    "./index.d.ts",
    "./index.js",
    "./my-class.js",
    "./my-class.d.ts",
    "./my-interface.d.ts"
  ]
```

... and when consuming the package (once it's published and installed in another project) can be done in the following ways:

```
import * as ngLib from '@my-org/ng-lib'
import { MyClass } from '@my-org/ng-lib'
import { MyInterface } from '@my-org/ng-lib'
import { MyClass } from '@my-org/ng-lib/my-class'
import { MyInterface } from '@my-org/ng-lib/my-interface'
```

**END EDIT**

The **declaration** property in tsconfig.json will emit .d.ts files describing the 'shape' of your exported objects.

```
// tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "listFiles": true,
    "noImplicitUseStrict": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And if it's a complicated package, I'll have separate modules and aggregate them in the index.ts like so:

```
// index.ts
export * from './module-one'
export * from './module-two'
export * from './module-three'
```

You can also have sub-directories, each with their own indexes.

This will create both the index.js and index.d.ts files, which allows the following:

```
import * as ngLib from '@my-org/ng-lib'
import { ModuleOne } from '@my-org/ng-lib/module-one'
import { SubModuleOne } from '@my-org/ng-lib/submodules/submodule-one'
```

Comment: This scans through my entire files and creates a `.d.ts` for every single file that i have. I have already created my interfaces. I just want to export those into a single file. All my interface files are in a directory `./interfaces` and I have created a `index.d.ts` including which files I do want exposed. So how do I just export that?